# Looping posts of a custom post type in diffrent columns

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type "case_studies" i want posts from this, to arrange in a following way.

```
<div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
    IMAGE
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
    TEXT
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
    IMAGE
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
    TEXT
</div>
<!--      
Column Ends  
3rd & 4th posts
-->
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        IMAGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        IMAGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
<!--
Column Ends
 -->
```

Then again first & second post type column after that again 4th & 5th post type column same loop goes on. note that each column ends after 2 posts & styles are diffrent. how can i achieve this

in short odd columns must have 2 posts which wrapped with col-sm-3, even columns also have 2 posts each one wrapper with col-sm-6.

Comment: Simply create a custom render function in your `function.php` and then call it in `content-case_studies.php`

Comment: @Mederic already post type created want to loop the above way.

Comment: I know its created. I explained how to render it in frontend

Comment: @Mederic rendering in front end in this way is the issue can yo show how to?

Comment: First go read this [ask] then please take the [tour] because this isn't a free coding forum.

Comment: Help appriciated from someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies') );
    $Inc = 1;

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   

            <?php if($Inc==1){ ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <?php }else if($Inc==2){ ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>


            <?php }else if($Inc==3){ ?>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }else if($Inc==4){ ?>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php 
            if($Inc==4){
                $Inc =1;
            }
            $Inc++;
            endwhile;       
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @vel you are an angle.

Comment: did you check the post count?

Comment: what you mean archive slider